# Intercepting DNS query in PacketTunnelProvider for blocking domains

Tags: ios, swift, openvpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I have developed a VPN application with PacketTunnelProvider that connects to the OpenVPN server. It works perfectly fine. Now I have the following requirements.

1. The user should be able to block a particular domain, such as [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) while staying connected to the VPN server.

For the above requirement, I need to capture the DNS request for facebook.com and see if it is in the block list provided by the user and block the DNS request.

I don't have to have multiple network extensions, I need to handle it from one Packettunnel provider that is already handling OpenVPN connection.

Can anyone help me here with this use case?